# Shopify: How to return shippingAddress.formatted in Japanese

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

My query:

```
<<<'QUERY'
    query ($id: ID!) {
        subscriptionContract(id: $id) {
            originOrder {
                shippingAddress {
                    formatted(withCompany: true, withName: true)
                }
            }
        }
    }
QUERY;
```

It return formatted like this below

```
"formatted": [
    "Japan 〒105-0003",
    "Tokyo 港区",
    "西新橋一丁目8番1号",
    "REVZO虎ノ門9F",
    "元気",
    "太朗 筋肉様"
]
```

I want Japan and Tokyo will be 日本 and 東京都.
How do I translate it to Japanese?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use @Shopify/address

https://github.com/Shopify/quilt/tree/main/packages/address

```
import AddressFormatter from '@shopify/address';

const address = {
  company: 'Shopify',
  firstName: '恵子',
  lastName: '田中',
  address1: '八重洲1-5-3',
  address2: '',
  city: '目黒区',
  province: 'JP-13',
  zip: '100-8994',
  country: 'JP',
  phone: '',
};

const addressFormatter = new AddressFormatter('ja');
await addressFormatter.format(address);
```